# What does `(req,res,next)` at bottom mean?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

```
router.post('/login', isNotLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (authError, user, info) => {
        if (authError) {
            console.error(authError);
            return next(authError);
        }
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('loginError', info.message);
            return res.redirect('/');
        }

        return req.login(user, (loginError) => {
            if (loginError) {
                console.error(loginError);
                return next(loginError);
            }

            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);// <-- this line
});
```

I'm trying to learning passport package from online lecture. But, I don't get this (req,res,next) at bottom. Can anybody help me out what does it mean?

Comment: did you add those `**`? If so, remove than and put a normal comment there, because right now this is invalid code. As for what it means: `(...)` after a function declaration is the standard execution operator, so that function will get executed with whatever's inside the `(...)` as arguments.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Why would they want to immediately execute a callback function?

Comment: That's not what they're doing. They're bootstrapping `passport`, which when executed will _generate_ an express middleware function, and then the code immediately calls that middleware function, rather than assigning it to some alias and then executing that alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(...)` after any function declaration is the standard execution operator:

```
const fn = function test() {
  return 'test';
}
```

will result in `fn` being a function.

```
const fn = (function test() {
  return 'test';
})();
```

will result in `fn` being the string `test` because the declared function gets run *before* the assignment happens, similar to:

```
const tempfunction = function() {
   return 'test';
};

const fn = tempFunction();
```

but without that intermediary `tempFunction` hanging around.

In that vein, the code you're showing is functionally equivalent to this:

```js
router.post("/login", isNotLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  // declare a passport authentication handler
  const authFn = (authError, user, info) => {
    if (authError) {
      console.error(authError);
      return next(authError);
    }
    if (!user) {
      req.flash("loginError", info.message);
      return res.redirect("/");
    }

    return req.login(user, loginError => {
      if (loginError) {
        console.error(loginError);
        return next(loginError);
      }

      return res.redirect("/");
    });
  };

  // call passport to generate an express middleware function
  const passportMiddleware = passport.authenticate("local", authFn);

  // run
  passportMiddleware(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Passport Doc](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/):

> `authenticate()`'s function signature is standard Connect middleware, which makes it convenient to use as route middleware in Express applications.

So, basically the connect middleware has this type of structure:

```
function middleware(req, res, next){
   //do something
}
```

You can check what are connect type middlewares from `express.js` [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

But ultimately, `passport.authenticate()` returns a function which is identical to the above signature.

So when you do

```
passport.authenticate(.....)(req, res, next)
```

You are doing this:

```
(function(req, res, next){
   //do something
})(req, res, next)
```

And you are basically passing `express.request` as `req`, `express.response` as `res` and `next` which is pointer to the next handler.